# Can boto3 paginator be ordered?

Tags: amazon-web-services, boto, boto3

I'm writing a script to remove older snapshots from RDS so I'd like to order paginator results by snapshot create time. Is there a way to do that in boto3's paginator classes?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, this isn't really possible.  This would require support on the service side and the RDS service does not provide any ability to order the pagination.  Boto3 is simply returning what the service provides.

You could, of course, create a list of all of the returned snapshots and then sort that list in Python.  The viability of that approach depends on the number of snapshots that will be returned.